# How to change date format for the grouping of object property using Import-Excel in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Moving further in the concept of Group-Object addressed here: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75215795/how-to-add-nested-grouping-of-psobject-properties-based-imported-values-of-an-ex)
I'm using the Import-Excel module to import the date column inside the powershell object arraylist. Which I'm further using to group the data. However, everytime I group the data for date it also takes in the time-stamp values as well. I know there is a parameter in the library called -AsDate  that allows user to convert the date from numerical form, however in my case. It is printing the date in the format of MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss. I only want to have MM-dd-yyyy so that I can use it to group my data.

Here's the sample data table in excel file:

```
Date               Type       Amount    
1-1-2021 3:10:06 AM   Level 1     $1.00 
1-1-2021 5:11:03 AM   Level 1     $2.00 
1-2-2021 4:34:06 AM   Level 1     $3.00 
1-1-2021 1:56:05 AM   Level 2     $4.00 
1-1-2021 7:23:04 AM   Level 2     $5.00 
1-2-2021 9:16:00 AM   Level 1     $4.00
```

I tried adding the Date Object inside the Group-Object Block but the root cause of the splitting object is the Timestamp values. In addition to that I went through the repository of the module and followed the discussions andd realized that there is no support of date formatting only the conversion of numerical date value to date under the -AsDate parameter.

**Here's the updated source code as per my previous question**

```
$result = Import-Excel -Path "C:\SampleData.xlsx" -AsDate Date | Group-Object Date | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Group-Object Type | ForEach-Object {
            $sum = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([double[]] $_.Group.Amount)
            $_.Group[0].Amount = $sum.ToString('C2')
            $_.Group[0].Date = Get-Date $_.Group[0].Date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
            $_.Group[0]
    }
}
$result
```

**Current Result:**

```
Date    Type        Amount  
1-1-2021    Level 1     $1.00   
1-1-2021    Level 1     $2.00   
1-2-2021    Level 1     $3.00   
1-1-2021    Level 2     $4.00   
1-1-2021    Level 2     $5.00   
1-2-2021    Level 1     $4.00
```

**Expected Result**

```
Date    Type        Amount  
1-1-2021    Level 1     $3.00       
1-2-2021    Level 1     $7.00   
1-1-2021    Level 2     $9.00
```

Code Credits to @Santiago Squarzon for Guiding through the Group-Object Process. Thank you for providing the explaination.

Comment: `Group-Object Date` --> `Group-Object {$_.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")}`

Answer (score 0):

After giving the `-AsDate` parameter a try I'm not seeing the values for the `Date` column being converted to a [`DateTime` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0) so I would recommend you to not use in this case and just let `Get-Date` parse the string for you. To group the objects by their day (excluding the time) you can use a [*calculated expression* with `Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3#group-object) to group the values by the [`.Date` property of `DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-date).

```
$result = Import-Excel "C:\SampleData.xlsx" | Group-Object { (Get-Date $_.Date).Date } | ForEach-Object {
    # get the date of this group and convert it to the desired date string format
    $date = Get-Date $_.Name -Format M/d/yyyy
    # group by Type each group
    $_.Group | Group-Object Type | ForEach-Object {
        # sum the Amount of all objects in this group
        $sum = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([double[]] $_.Group.Amount)
        # update the Amount property of the first object
        $_.Group[0].Amount = $sum.ToString('C2')
        # update the Date property of the first object
        $_.Group[0].Date   = $date
        # ouput the first object
        $_.Group[0]
    }
}
```

Output on test data would become:

```
Date     Type    Amount
----     ----    ------
1/1/2021 Level 1 $3.00
1/1/2021 Level 2 $9.00
1/2/2021 Level 1 $7.00
```